# Sync data between devices with windows universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows, win-universal-app

I am new with universal windows app development, and I am looking for some way to share data (on each device database) created on windows phone app with windows app and vice versa, I don't want involve a webserver to manage this, the only exception maybe is the user's onedrive, I'm think if it's possible the windows app (rt or desktop) version run a little service to handle this over wi-fi? or some way tho backup and restore database using onedrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the roaming app data. I don't know how big your database is. But to maintain integrity you could serialize each table into JSON and store it. It's easy as pie:

```
var roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
roamingSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello World";
```

If that isn't enough for you, you can even store a file inside the roaming folder:

```
var roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
StorageFile database = await roamingFolder.CreateFileAsync("mydb.sqlite", 
   CreateCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700362.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464917.aspx#roaming_app_data

Comment: Thank you, this will help me, the database is small now, but if it get bigger, I'll find a way to use roaming app data with the new content not entire database...

Comment: @Fred I am in a similar situation here, But I also need the user to login  to OneDrive with a different account from that of the connected account. Can this be done? If so could you help me out here thanks.

Comment: When I tried it, it took very long to sync and sometimes did not sync (not reliable). Also, be careful not to overwrite the data in the process.

Comment: @BrunoLemos how do you test that? can you do backup and restore on button click?